# Angular1 <-> Angular2 Bridge accessing $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-upgrade

I use the following upgrade/downgrade bridge https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html to have *Angular1* and *Angular2* side by side in one application.

My question is if there is any possiblity to access *Angular1* `$rootScope` from the *Angular2* service. To be clear I am **not asking about** what is the equivalent for `$rootScope` in *Angular2*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I will answer my own question.

You have to upgrade the `$rootScope` in the following manner:

```
upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Provider('$rootScope')
```

Then it can be injected in the Angular2 service like follows:

```
@Injectable()    
class ExampleAngular2Service {
    constructor(@Inject('$rootScope') private _rootScope: any) {}
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do this but it says $rootScope is not defined...:( Is there anything else do I need to take case of?

Answer (score 7):

All that's needed is:

```
@Injectable()    
class ExampleAngular2Service {
  constructor(@Inject('$rootScope') private _rootScope: IRootScopeService) {}
}
```

You don't have to upgrade anything, it's there by default. See http://www.spaprogrammer.com/2017/03/inject-rootscope-into-angular-2.html

Tested on Angular 6 Hybrid using the now [recommended](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade):

```
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
```

You can also do this with `$scope`

```
@Inject('$scope') private $scope: IScope
```